# How to explain how the DIAC and TRIAC works in a digitally controlled fan regulator circuit?

Tags: capacitor, triac, fan, diac

There are two version of the circuit that do the same thing. One with capacitor, and, one without.

The schematics below depict the circuit needed for diac/triac activation properly. (I have missed out a few components for achieving the full wave rectification; ignore that).

**1. With capacitor/resistors**

[image]

**2. Without capacitor/resistors**

[image]

Both circuits do the same dimming operation. Assume there is a AC fan connected in the output end. I came across this [video](https://youtu.be/Kl71Kt0QM9A) which explains a traditional fan regulator circuit. However, I am unable to explains what happens in circuit #1.

How does the capacitor in circuit #1 work? What is its function? Is it for smoothing the chopped output AC (which goes into the fan)?

I am hoping someone explain circuit #2 with reference to #1. So which of these circuits are ideal for a fan speed regulation?

Comment: Please draw a schematic. Click on edit and the schematic symbol.

Comment: Nice diagrams - but rather hard to follow. alas it greatly helps answers if you provide a std sryle cct diagram using eg the provided editor. | Whatever works is OK. CCT 2 needs some series resistors for the input opto coupler.

Comment: Schematics are up!! Sorry for last time... :)